# Questions about removing ios photo asset in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, photo

This source code is a photo app like the iPhone's photo app.
When you launch the app, each `Asset` that is a `CollectionViewCell` is shown.

What I would like to ask is the ability to select and delete an image asset. If you look at the iPhone photo app, you can press the select button to select photos and delete and share selected photos. You can choose as many photos as you want rather than just one. I have implemented `@IBAction selectButtonPressed`.

```
class PhotoCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sortButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var trashButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    // MARK:- Properties
    var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>? {
        didSet {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.collectionView?.reloadSections(IndexSet(0...0))
            }
        }
    }
    var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection?

    // MARK:- Privates
    private let cellReuseIdentifier: String = "photoCell"
    private lazy var cachingImageManager: PHCachingImageManager = {
        return PHCachingImageManager()
    }()

    // MARK:- Life Cycle
    deinit {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().unregisterChangeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBAction func sortButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        if (self.sortButton.title == "In the past") {
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
                                                             ascending: false)]
            self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
            self.sortButton.title = "The latest"
        } else if (self.sortButton.title == "The latest") {
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate",
                                                             ascending: true)]
            self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
            self.sortButton.title = "In the past"
        }
    }

     @IBAction func seletButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if (self.sortButton.isEnabled == true) {
            self.sortButton.isEnabled = false
            self.actionButton.isEnabled = true
            self.trashButton.isEnabled = true
        } else if (self.sortButton.isEnabled == false) {
            self.sortButton.isEnabled = true
            self.actionButton.isEnabled = false
            self.trashButton.isEnabled = false
        }

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            //Delete Photo
            PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(self.fetchResult!)
            },
            completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                NSLog("\nDeleted Image -> %@", (success ? "Success":"Error!"))
                if(success){
                }else{
                print("Error: \(error)")
                }
        })
    }
}

extension PhotoCollectionViewController {

    private func configureCell(_ cell: PhotoCollectionViewCell,
                               collectionView: UICollectionView,
                               indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let asset: PHAsset = self.fetchResult?.object(at: indexPath.item) else { return }

        let manager: PHCachingImageManager = self.cachingImageManager
        let handler: (UIImage?, [AnyHashable:Any]?) -> Void = { image, _ in

            let cellAtIndex: UICollectionViewCell? = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

            guard let cell: PhotoCollectionViewCell = cellAtIndex as? PhotoCollectionViewCell
                else { return }

            cell.imageView.image = image
        }

        manager.requestImage(for: asset,
                             targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100),
                             contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill,
                             options: nil,
                             resultHandler: handler)
    }
}

// MARK:- UICollectionViewDataSource
extension PhotoCollectionViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.fetchResult?.count ?? 0
    }
}

extension PhotoCollectionViewController {

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: PhotoCollectionViewCell
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellReuseIdentifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                                 forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let cell: PhotoCollectionViewCell = cell as? PhotoCollectionViewCell else {
            return
        }

        self.configureCell(cell, collectionView: collectionView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

// MARK:- UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension PhotoCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        guard let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout =
            self.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return CGSize.zero}

        let numberOfCellsInRow: CGFloat = 4
        let viewSize: CGSize = self.view.frame.size
        let sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets = flowLayout.sectionInset

        let interitemSpace: CGFloat = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (numberOfCellsInRow - 1)

        var itemWidth: CGFloat
        itemWidth = viewSize.width - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right - interitemSpace
        itemWidth /= numberOfCellsInRow

        let itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)

        return itemSize
    }
}

extension PhotoCollectionViewController {
    private func updateCollectionView(with changes: PHFetchResultChangeDetails<PHAsset>) {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return }

        // 업데이트는 삭제, 삽입, 다시 불러오기, 이동 순으로 진행합니다
        if let removed: IndexSet = changes.removedIndexes, removed.count > 0 {
            collectionView.deleteItems(at: removed.map({
                IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0)
            }))
        }

        if let inserted: IndexSet = changes.insertedIndexes, inserted.count > 0 {
            collectionView.insertItems(at: inserted.map({
                IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0)
            }))
        }

        if let changed: IndexSet = changes.changedIndexes, changed.count > 0 {
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: changed.map({
                IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0)
            }))
        }

        changes.enumerateMoves { fromIndex, toIndex in
            collectionView.moveItem(at: IndexPath(item: fromIndex, section: 0),
                                    to: IndexPath(item: toIndex, section: 0))
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver
extension PhotoCollectionViewController: PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {

    private func resetCachedAssets() {
        self.cachingImageManager.stopCachingImagesForAllAssets()
    }

    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        guard let fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset> = self.fetchResult
            else { return }

        guard let changes: PHFetchResultChangeDetails<PHAsset> =
            changeInstance.changeDetails(for: fetchResult)
            else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.resetCachedAssets()
            self.fetchResult = changes.fetchResultAfterChanges

            if changes.hasIncrementalChanges {
                self.updateCollectionView(with: changes)
            } else {
                self.collectionView?.reloadSections(IndexSet(0...0))
            }
        }
    }
}

extension PhotoCollectionViewController {

    // MARK:- Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)

        self.sortButton.title = "In the past"
        self.actionButton.isEnabled = false
        self.trashButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

`AssetCollection` can be selected by clicking the `select` `barButtonItem` in the upper right corner of the screen, and I want to delete or share selected pictures.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please [edit] your question and clearly explain what it is that you need help with. Do not reply in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can perfore delete action on phAsset as below:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
    //Delete Photo
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(delShotsAsset)
    },
    completionHandler: {(success, error)in
        NSLog("\nDeleted Image -> %@", (success ? "Success":"Error!"))
        if(success){

        }else{
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
})
```

Comment: thank you. Bansi Hirpara !!
I will add one more question. The code you are prompted to press "selectButton" asks if you want to delete all image assets.

The code I would like to implement is to press "selectButton" so that I can select the image I want to delete. After that, pressing "deleteButton" will delete the selected images! The above code with your code. It's corrected

Comment: For that you have to make an array storing all selected phasset than perform above code snippet. By doing so apple will ask you to whether delete images that you selected or not and also that popup shows image count same as passed array count.